# Multiplication in object javascript

Tags: javascript

I have object like this :

```
var item = {
 A : 3,
 B : 4,
 C : parseInt(A*B)
}
```

I want to perform multiplication, C = A*B , i have tried to do multiplication as specfied in above object but did not work . How can i do that . Please help me

Comment: I don't think you can refer to members of the same literal from within the literal.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You could reach the desired result with a simple function.

```js
var item = {
 A : 3,
 B : 4,
 C : function() {
       return this.A * this.B;
     }
}

console.log(item.C());
```

Comment: Then you can't access `c` like a regular property, `C` is now a function. Evern though I did not give you the -1